# Is it possible to upload from Google Drive into another web service?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking into integrating a SaaS product with Google Drive. Is it possible to allow Drive users to authorize the uploading of a Drive file to another remote storage location?

For example, right now, I can download a file directly into the Google Drive folder on the computer, from the web service. I could also use the OS file handler window to choose the Google Drive folder to upload a file to the web service. But that requires depending on the OS to browse for files on that specific device. iOS doesn't allow that at all.

Does the API allow for direct file transfer between Drive and another web service?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drive API allows you to read and write Drive files programmatically. Then it's up to developers to implement any syncing/file transfer logic between Drive and another web service. So yes, in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works in practice:

[Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) is IaaS solution (backed by us) that allows you to upload files from Google Drive, Dropbox, Box, OneDrive, Evernote, and other sources. Users also can upload images from social networks, such as Facebook, Instagram, and Flickr:

https://uploadcare.com/upload-sources/

You can even upload a photo directly from your device camera.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the remote file location is either Dropbox, Box, or Google Drive, you can also use the Cloud Rail Single Interface for that, and very easily.

The Cloud Rail Single Interface allows you to use the same functions, with the same inputs and outputs, across the above Cloud Storage services.The choice of which particular service to use all takes place when instating the class. So for example the line:

```
        cs = new com.cloudrail.si.cloudStorage.GoogleDrive(
          this, 
          /** Your Client ID **/, 
          /** Your Client Secret**/
        );
```

just needs to be changed to, for example, if you are transferring the file to Dropbox: "com.cloudrail.si.cloudStorage.Dropbox", with all of the other functions working the same to the newly substantiated service.

Disclaimer: I am employed by CloudRail.